# Unhealthy NEG that potentially lead to Server Error Page

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, load-balancing, gke-networking

Attached is my NEG which is unhealthy

[image]

Though I have set the firewall that allows health check
[image]

The IP is connected to GKE instance which are all healthy now

[image]

And I got this page when I access GKE's API from webpage
(here http://34.160.164.35/health)
[image]

What could I do to address it?

My mci.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: MultiClusterIngress
metadata:
  name: terraback-ingress
  namespace: terraback
  labels:
    version: v1
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      backend:
        serviceName: terraback-mcs
        servicePort: 8080
```

My mcs.yaml

```
# Copyright 2021 Google LLC
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# The hello service provides a load-balancing proxy over the hello-app
# pods. By specifying the type as a 'LoadBalancer', Kubernetes Engine will
# create an external HTTP load balancer.
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: MultiClusterService
metadata:
  name: terraback-mcs
  namespace: terraback
  labels:
    version: v1
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      selector:
        app: terraback
      ports:
        - name: web
          protocol: TCP
          port: 8080
          targetPort: 4000
---
```

Comment: Can you check if your service is running fine? And the pods are also functioning? Seems to me this is a problem with the application pods.

Comment: @zer0 I have checked all the pods and their logs, all of them are running fine.

Comment: And can you verify that the service label is attached to the pods? And they are correctly being 'attached' to the service?

Comment: @zer0 yes they are, in fact they are functioning when I set it up

Comment: Okay, next thing you can do is temporarily change your service type to `LoadBalancer` and try to access it, without using an Endpoint Group. Just to confirm your service is serving the content right.

Comment: I got it solved..it's due to we need to return a 200 at "/" path...

Answer (score 1):

I got it solved..it's due to we need to return a 200 at "/" path...

Comment: Please explain with a bit more detail